# Excel file when save as CSV the sum amount is different by 1c

Tags: excel, csv, floating-point

I have a SSRS report getting data from SQL which then gets exported to Excel, opened and saved to CSV (due to formatting). My issue is that the Excel & CSV file has the total amount correct but the individual lines when summing up is 1c off

Here's a brief look of the Excel file:

[image]

- D2 is the total amount is calculated by my report
- E2+ are the individual lines total (if posting key 50 then value, if key
  is 40 than the negative of that  `=IF(A2=50,B2,B2*-1)`
- E1 is the `=SUM(E1:E500)`
- F1 is a `=IF(D2-E1,"T","F")`

So you can see in the Excel file the lines total match the report total. My issue is that once its saved to CSV, the Report total remains the same but when you open and do the same calculations as I did in column E, E1 comes out as 980138.62 (1c out)

The link to the excel sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ierIHo9PQA5FThThReOSQtoGAotuwhCq/view?usp=sharing

Download and save as csv, open up in excel and readd the calculations same as columns E ie
each individual lines: `=IF(D2-E1,"T","F")` & then get the column total `=SUM(E1:E500)` into a new column and its out by 1c. And I can't see which line is causing the 1c difference.

My question is.. How do I correct this? The background is the Net/QTY value from SQL is a float data but I have cast to 2 decimal places. Generated a report into SSRS then export to Excel then save as CSV which then gets loaded into SAP. SAP finds that the total amount and the individual line amounts do not match each other off and the program errors.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the Excel intermediate format. Can Excel do anything that SQL can't (except plotting, maybe ...)?

Comment: Yes the SSRS report when export to csv loses the format needed. The above details is simplified to show only what is required and where the issue lies. Ideally if I can export the number as a text is another I could try but the ' does not store the number as a text and causes other issues.

Comment: Provide all information needed to reproduce the problem in the question. The data should be in the question itself, not provided via a link, especially not as a link that requires logging in and requesting permission to access. To provide that data, I suggest you format the Excel cells to 20 significant digits of precision and export them in some text/CSV format, so that somebody else can load the data into Excel or other software and reproduce the original values exactly. It might also be good to test deleting various rows to reduce the size of the data while retaining the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise it was restricted, its a google drive link with read access. I have changed it to allow anyone with link to view. The problem with cutting the file down to size is the 1c will disappear, the problem with providing csv, it too won't work either.

Comment: I downloaded the spreadsheet, opened it with Excel 12.3.6 for Mac, saved it as CSV, closed it, opened the CSV file, and entered `=SUM(E2:E500)` in F1. The sum was shown as 980138.61, not 980138.62 as reported in the question. (Note the question states to use `=SUM(E1:E500)`, but that is incorrect as it includes the existing sum in E1.)

Comment: In rows 153 and 193, you have values 6158.295 and 6170.175, respectively. I suspect those are contributing to rounding errors in whatever version of Excel you are using. If they are both rounded up instead of each summed as half a cent, that adds one cent to the total. You should look at the CSV file and see how those numbers appear there. Failing that, I would test whether the problem reproduces if rows other than those two are deleted.

Comment: OK now it comes back to why my data from CAST(ROUND(Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) is returning to 3 decimal places. Thank you for highlighting the issue to me